# Using super() in subclasses AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

To explain my question I wrote some code.

This is the superclass:

```
package

{
    public class Cclass
    {
        public function Cclass(a:int, words:String)
        {
            trace("i am:"+a," years old and i will:"+words," you");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the subclass:

```
package
{
    public class Dclass extends Cclass
    {
        public function Dclass(a:int, words:String)
        {
            super(a, words);
            trace(a, words);

        }
    }
}
```

When I test it, I get the following output:

```
i am:5  years old and i will:kill  you
i am:6  years old and i will:strangle  you
6 strangle
```

The super runs the constructor of the `Cclass` and does the same again, however if I try to run it without the "super( a, words)" it doesn't work which is understandable. My question is how to make the `Dclass` only display the `trace(a, words);` without running the constructor of `Cclass`. I want to get this output:

```
i am:5  years old and i will:kill  you
6 strangle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extending a class the AS3 run-time will automatically call the base classes constructor.
So you can assume when extending a class super.constructor will always happen whether you write the code in or not.
This is why it is good practice to never include any code in the constructor.

This doesn't mean that with a little massaging you can't fix it

```
public class Cclass{
  public function Cclass( ){
  }
  public function doTrace( a:int, words:String):void{
    trace("i am:"+a," years old and i will:"+words," you");
  }
}

public class Dclass extends Cclass{
    public function Dclass(){
      //super();// this is implied that it will always happen
    }
    public function myTrace(a:int, words:String):void{
        this.doTrace(a, words);
    }
}

var dClass:Dclass = new Dclass()
dClass.myTrace(5,'kill')
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner so it really is good practice to leave the constructor empty? I've never read that before. Still, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Super constructors always run in actionscript, if you don't declare it, it'll automatically run it anyways.  Best way to do this is to make it a function.

```
public class cc {

     public function doSomething(a:int, words:String)
     {
         trace("i am:"+a," years old and i will:"+words," you");
     }
}

public class dd extends cc {

     override public function doSomething(a:int, words:String) {
         trace("i am:"+a," years old and i will:"+words," you");
     }
}

var d = new dd();
d.doSomething(5, 'kill');
```